# debian and yum packages - is there a way we can set max mem % and CPU % limits?

Tags: linux, debian, rpm, ulimit, limits

Is there a hard limit we can set on `Debian` and `RPM` packages? My thought is to put 20% CPU, 20% Memory and 200 MB Disk Usage hard limits. So the package can play within those limits and not beyond that.

On Googling I found bind and pam.limits can be used. Has anyone used this before? Are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is just a container so it is unlikely to set a limit on that.

If your package installs a service, the best way to impose limits on services nowadays I think is to leverage the fact that systemd gives you easy access to `cgroups` ; [control groups](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) where you can set a number of [resource limits](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

For a service *"foo"* with set resource limits either in the unit file of `foo.service` itself or create for instance a [`foo.slice`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html)  and set options such as:

```
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=20%
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryMax=bytes
```

Comment: Yes. It runs as a service. I'll look into this. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I have added this to /lib/systemd/system/my-package.service file. To test I have set the max memory to 1 MB. And it still consumes more than 1 MB.

Comment: Where do I place this? under [Service] block?

Comment: the settings are indeed valid in a `[Service]` block

Comment: I still see the service taking 23% of CPU and RAM. I have those attributes placed under `[Service]` block.

Comment: Is the systemd release > 213?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04. That has systemd version 229

Comment: Could it be because of cores on the machine? The documentation says each the % can go beyond 100% based on the number of cores the machine has.

Comment: But if this is the case, then why is the memory still going beyond the threshold? I had set MemoryMax to 500MB, but when I was load testing it went beyond 1.5 GB RAM. I have now set MemoryHigh=10% and MemoryMax=15%. Is there something wrong I am doing here?